# Найти сумму чисел в последовательности

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

Нужно найти сумму чисел в следующей последовательности: 2, 22, 222, 2222, ..., 2(n), - где, n - количество разрядов в последнем числе

Для примера, n = 5 последнее число будет 22222, а сумма чисел в последовательности - 24690.

```
n = 5  # кол-во разрядов
last_num = 0  # итоговое число
i = 1  # счетчик разрядов
sum = 0  # 2 + 22 + 222 + 2222 + 22222 => 24690

while n > 0:
    last_num += 2 * i
    i *= 10
    n -= 1
print(last_num)
while last_num != 0:
    sum += last_num // 10
    last_num //= 10
print(sum)
```

Понимаю, что код кривой, так как только начал учит Python.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как найти сумму чисел, поскольку условие sum += last_num // 10 "отсекает" первую двойку и по итогу сумма получается из чисел 2222 + 222 + 22 + 2 = 2468, вместо 22222 + 2222 + 222 + 22 + 2 = 24690.

Comment: На какую тему задача-то? Например, на рекурсию.

Comment: только цикл while, без рекурсий и функций

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Основная ошибка - излишняя сложность. У вас идея верная, но уберите две строки. Python призывает к лаконичности и ясности, начинайте решение с продумывания самого лаконичного и ясного варианта. Но ясность важнее лаконичности.

```
n = 5  # кол-во разрядов
last_num = 0  # итоговое число
i = 1  # счетчик разрядов
sum1 = 0  # 2 + 22 + 222 + 2222 + 22222 => 24690

while n > 0:
    last_num += 2 * i
    i *= 10
    n -= 1
    sum1 += last_num
print(sum1)
```

Comment: не используйте зарезервированные слова для своих переменных `sum`

Comment: @n1tr0xs, рудимент авторского кода. Исправил. Спасибо.

Comment: Благодарен за ответ и за советы, опыта просто очень мало в написании кода.

Answer (score 9):

У вас появляется ошибка, потому что вы отсекаете последнюю цифру дважды (`sum += last_num // 10` и `last_num //= 10`). Нужно убрать одно из действий:

```
n = 5  # кол-во разрядов
last_num = 0  # итоговое число
i = 1  # счетчик разрядов
sum_ = 0  # 2 + 22 + 222 + 2222 + 22222 => 24690

while n > 0:
    last_num += 2 * i
    i *= 10
    n -= 1
print(last_num)
while last_num != 0:
    sum_ += last_num
    last_num //= 10
print(sum_)
```

> 22222
> 24690

Кстати, код вполне нормальный. Только имя `sum` в python зарезервировано под функцию, поэтому его не стоит использовать в качестве названия переменной.

В таких случаях можно добавлять '_' к концу имени.

Comment: Ростислав, вы правы, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Если вопрос для вас закрыт, один из ответов можно отметить как решение.

Comment: её вообще отсекать не надо :-) Но + 1 за скорость:-)

Comment: Спасибо. Только кого - её?

Comment: "вы отсекаете последнюю цифру дважды" - см. мой Ответ

Comment: Да, у вас сделано проще. Я оставил авторский код для наглядности.

Answer (score 8):

Можно не отсекать, а накапливать:

- `term` - слагаемое: 0, 2, 22, 222, ..., 2(n);
- `sum_` - накопительная сумма: 2 + 22 + 222 + ...;
- `n` - счётчик итераций.

Проще некуда:

```
n = 5
sum_ = 0
term = 0
while n > 0:
    term = 10 * term + 2
    sum_ += term
    n -= 1
print(sum_)
```

Если применить немного изобретательности, слагаемые можно считать напрямую. На одну переменную меньше, но понять что происходит сложнее:

```
n = 5
sum_ = 0
while n > 0:
    sum_ += 2 * (10 ** n - 1) // 9
    n -= 1
print(sum_)
```

И ещё немного изобретательности: есть замкнутая формула для ответа. Одна строка и долгие объяснения почему так:

```
n = 5
print(2 * ((10 ** (n + 1) - 1) // 9 - n - 1) // 9)
```

Comment: Если хотите узнать как получить последнюю формулу, напишите комментарий - добавлю объяснение.

Answer (score 7):

В одну строчку по приколу, но тут используется строковое представление цифры для удобства:

```py
n = 5
k = '2'
print(sum(int(k*i) for i in range(1, n+1)))
# 24690
```

Просто "размножаем" цифру нужное число раз (для этого она должна быть строкой), превращаем в число, всё это в цикле и дальше суммируем.

Comment: Я могу также но без строк. Вот: `print(sum(2 * (10 ** (i + 1) - 1) // 9 for i in range(5)))`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Не вопрос. Но: 1) через символьную цифру код гораздо понятнее, 2) не факт, что возведение в степень будет сильно быстрее, чем мой метод с размножением и приведением в `int` (хотя это и затратная операция). P.S. В колабе мой код реально стабильно немного, но быстрее ))

Comment: Я не спорю, ваш код яснее. На действительно больших числах возведение в степень будет быстрее чем вызов `int()`. Проверено.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну, если от `n > 500` где-то, то да )  Но для таких лучше уж обычный цикл написать и домножать в цикле на 10 )

Comment: Нет, как раз `int()` и умножение в цикле имеют одну скорость - квадрат от количества цифр. Возведение в степень быстрее квадрата.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Но ведь у вас цикл `for i in range(5)` тоже есть. Что-то я не понимаю )  В первом коде вот как вы делаете - домножаете каждый раз и прибавляете, я про это имел в виду, что это оптимальнее. Оно сильно быстрее, я проверил )

Comment: Я вас запутал, извините. Да, для цикла вариант с умножить/прибавить лучше чем `int()`, вы правы. Это всё летания в облаках. :)

Comment: по-моему - это самое элегантное решение. С подходом умножать строку можно применить все что угодно, любой цикл (for, while) или tuple comprehension, как в вашем ответе

Comment: @Dmitry Только кортежи тут не при чём, это генераторное выражение или что-то в этом роде, на выходе получается генератор с "ленивым" исполнением, а не кортежи )  Но я кажется нашёл ссылку, откуда это заблуждение может расти )

Comment: @CrazyElf то да, скобки увидел, на автомате кортеж в голове. Это просто генератор)

Answer (score 6):

Еще вариант:

```py
from functools import reduce

n = 5
d = 2
res = [0] * n
q = 0
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    q, res[i-1] = divmod(q + i * d, 10)

print(*res, sep='')                     # 24690
print(''.join(map(str,res)))            # 24690
print(reduce(lambda x, y: 10*x+y, res)) # 24690
```

Или так:

```py
from itertools import accumulate, repeat

n = 5
d = 2
print(sum(accumulate(repeat(d, n), lambda x, y: x * 10 + y))) # 24690
```

Comment: ТС изучает цикл `while`, а вы с функциями высшего порядка пришли. :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, главное мозг нагрузить, а потом проще будет :) Может поймет не с первого захода, так со второго.